# Pattern.quote not working for \037 character when it is passed to a spark program via oozie

Tags: java, oozie

I am passing ASCII character \037 (to be used as a field delimiter) to a spark program via oozie. In my oozie property file i have given the value like,

```
delimiterArg=\\\037
```

In my spark program, I am trying to split the line as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String column1 = line.split(Pattern.quote(args[0]));                    
}
```

But it is not working. But if I use without `Pattern.quote`, it is working,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String column1 = line.split(args[0]));                               
 }
```

I would like to use Pattern.quote() as it will handle special characters like Pipe (|). Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Here is my complete scenario

I need to pass the delimiter \037 to spark program which is triggered via oozie job.I will use this as a field delimiter for processing data.

In order to pass \037 to spark program I have to give \\037 in my job.properties file.

Now that i have received this value in my spark program and trying to split the input string. Issue is that

```
String column1 =  line.split(Pattern.quote(args[0])); // Not Working


String column1 =  line.split(args[0])); // Working
```

Comment: Why the double backslash?

Comment: @EJP i need to pass that argument to my spark program via oozie. So in the job.properties file i am giving like delimitterArg=\\037. So this value will be passed to Spark program as "\037".

Comment: Why? Have you tried it with a single backslash? Or are you just guessing?

Comment: @EJP Yes i have tried all possible combinations.When i give without backslash it will just pass 037. I have verified this from Spark application log.

Comment: So i printed out the the hash code of the value i am getting from spark application and it gave me value of 2788536 (for  delimitterArg=\\037). Then i thought \037 will not be printed in log file as it is non printable, but it  worked when i tried to split the line!

Comment: I didn't ask about omitting the backslash. I asked about *one*. Either you've tried it or you haven't. Which is it? And what does the hashcode have to do with it?

Comment: Yes. I used \037 with one backslash. i tested two scenarios, i have passed the value from job.properties file , as i said above in my spark program i received value as 037. Then i hard coded the value in my spark program as \037 then it did worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144790/discussion-between-despicable-me-and-ejp).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the String you are passing to `Pattern.quote()` is not the string you intended.

Here is a test program:

```
public class MVCE
    {
    public static void main(String[] argv)
        {
        final String line = "ab\037cd\037ef";
        final String[] columns = line.split( Pattern.quote("\037") );
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(columns));
        }
    }
```

The output from this program is:

```
[ab, cd, ef]
```

I would debug your situation by adding a print statement to the beginning of your `main()` method so that you can see exactly what string is passed as `args[0]`.  I know nothing of oozie, but I do notice you show `\\037` as the value in its file.  Perhaps you have multiple levels of programs interpreting the bytes in various ways such that the five bytes (if it is ASCII or UTF-8) in your configuration file does not result in the intended/expected four Unicode characters in `args[0]`.

Comment: thank you. In fact i did print the values. i also think it is an issue with multiple level of programs interpreting the bytes. What i did was put a print on args[0] which resulted in \037. This is as expected but its hashCode() gave me value of 2788536 which is the hashCode i have gotten for five byte "\\037". But it did split the line when used directly (without Pattern.quote).

Comment: if i do a System.out.println("\037"); \037 wont be printed as it is non printable, but the args[0] got printed as \037 and it did split the line properly when used directly like  line.split(args[0]); @dsh